# Ubuntu 13.04 runs slow

Tags: drivers, 13.04, graphics, performance

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 13.04 32-bit on my PC, but it runs slow. I don't know why. I'm a new Linux user in general.

**Hardware**
• Processor: Intel Atom CPU N26000 1.60GHz x 4
• Graphics card: Intel Express Chipset says in Windows. Intel Coportation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx integrated graphics controller with Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.2, 128 bits)
• Hard disk: 313.9GB
• 1 GB RAM.

I do not know if I should install another distribution of Linux or another version of Ubuntu, but I need help please. Thanks. :(

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ubuntu. Can you please add the actual Graphics card type (Galium is a kind of generic Linux graphics driver) and the size of the RAM.

Comment: If you don't know your graphics card type, you can type the folowing in a terminal:

lspci | grep VGA

Comment: Sorry, thanks to the two for answering. the will add. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I improve overall system performance?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, My Laptop configuration is: Lenovo Z470
Core i5
nvidia GeForce (128 MB)
4 GB RAM
500 GB HDD
Anyway..
Run's perfectly fast windows 7 and 8, Tried bef. Xubuntu 12, Ubuntu 11, Linux Mint, Manjaro.. all of them runs awesome but, just basic xubuntu 13.10 and, its very slow, open any browser (Mozilla,Opera,Chrome) takes some time (more than 40 sec. just to open) and scrolling down a result pages on google is really slow.. any sugestion??

Comment: From what I can tell that the specs are not too bad, although the Linux Mint will be a little better fitment for the Hardware configuration you have.

Comment: Try the [Classic Desktop](http://askubuntu.com/q/58172/107450).  It is a lighter desktop and should be faster for you.

Comment: Last year I setup a similar system (CPU dual core Atom, 2GB RAM, Ubuntu 12.04LTS) for my brother for office work and internet browsing. Never had a hick-up. Your RAM is a little low for my taste (especially if you intend to run more than a couple instances of documents and web browser pages at the same time). You have quad core, so just add a GB of RAM and your system will be perfect for heavy office work and light to medium loads like video playback, multiple flash sites open, etc. Just don't expect to be able to run modern 3D games.

Answer (score 0):

In general, your system meets minimum requirements. Although its never going to fly, it should be able to run Ubuntu. But it [seems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284305/unity-2d-on-ubuntu-13-04-or-is-it-too-fast-to-matter) that 3D accelaration is not supported for the Atom N26000. Because Ubuntu's Unity desktop needs 3d, that could well be your problem.

If you dont really mind which desktop environment you use, why not give the LXDE desktop a try. Either by going into the Ubuntu software center and just install it, or uninstall Ubuntu and install Lubuntu. It will certainly boost your systems performance.

Good luck!